# Why does my Qi charging base squeal as my iPhone 8 charges?

Tags: iphone, charging

I just purchased a iPhone 8 and I was trying to charge it using my Qi charging base that I used on my former Nexus 6. The base worked fine on the Nexus 6 but on the iPhone, it squeals (not sure whether it is the iPhone or the base, but it sounds more like the base) and stops charging regularly. The charge level does go up during this process, but it is so irritating that I have to stop as I also fear damage to the iPhone. I used both the Nexus 6 and the iPhone USB power adapter and the result is the same. For me it seems that the iPhone pulls more power than the Qi base can support. It there a way to reduce the power drawn by the iPhone via wireless charging?

The Qi charger is a Itian model A2.

EDIT:
I found a solution to stop this Qi charger from squealing. I added a small padding on the bottom where the iPhone sits (around 1 cm or half inch) and the iPhone now is aligned well against the coil, which has stopped the squealing and charges at the expected rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could possibly be that the Qi base isn't actually a certified Qi product. As far as I can tell, [the only certified Qi charger from Itian is the K10.](https://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/products/details/2321/qi-fast-wireless-charger) In addition, [lack of Qi certification can mean incompatibility with some Qi devices, and at worst, potential damage to the device.](https://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/certified/)